# Maintenance Mode Screen Does Not Display

Tags: maintenance-mode

I'm using Drupal 8 with a purchased theme. I'm not 100% tech literate so apologies in advance if my question sounds dumb. After Drupal and the theme were initially installed I had no problems. After enabling maintenance mode and logging out the maintenance mode page displayed. Now, however, after logging back in, disabling maintenance mode and logging out, the original theme page does not display, and a Log in page displays. Repeating logging in/logging out, enabling/disabling maintenance mode only the Log in page displays, no maintenance mode page or original theme page. I've cleared the cache in Drupal and in my Chrome browser but it makes no difference.

Comment: I think you may be confusing terms. Theme is not the same as a page. There are many pages in a site, and theme is the design that "dresses them up" to look a certain way, all of them. Is your Log in page "dressed" in the new theme? What is the URL (link in browser location bar) you see on that page? What do you expect to see on the page you call "theme page"?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question. After much digging around it seems I disabled certain Anonymous Permissions, which messed how the maintenance mode and other (themes?) display. Yes, I likely confused "theme" with "page". This is my first time using Drupal and I have an enormous amount to learn. Investing in Drupal online training would be worth it. I can say however, that Drupal seems much better to work with compared to Joomla which I never liked. Drupal community support seems far more organized and responsive than Joomla, as well.

Comment: There is a lot of resources online for various Drupal features. It takes some practice at first, like with everything. Have you solved it then? I'm guessing it may have been "View published content" permission.

Comment: For sure practice, practice, practice. Yes, your guess is correct. It was the "View published content" permission setting. Problem solved. Thank you.